# Customize lapply() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply, data-manipulation

I would like to customize `lapply(df, FUN = mean)`

this works perfectly,

```
mtcars
means.mtcars <- lapply(mtcars, FUN = mean)
```

but I want to see the `prop.table(table(df$column))` and save them as a different row based on its different levels

```
mtcars$gear1 <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels = c(3,4,5))

my.mean <- function(df) {
   ifelse(is.numeric(df)== T, mean(df),
   ifelse(df$gear1 == 3, df$newColumn1 ==  as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df$gear1)))[1, "Freq"],
      ifelse( df$gear1 == 4, df$newColumn2 ==  as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df$gear1)))[2, "Freq"],
              df$newColumn3 == as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df$gear1)))[3, "Freq"]  )))
}

not.working <- lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.mean)
```

Expected results 
    means.mtcars and at the end newColumn1,newColumn2,newColumn3

```
            V1
mpg   20.090625
cyl    6.187500
disp 230.721875
hp   146.687500
drat   3.596563
wt     3.217250
qsec  17.848750
vs     0.437500
am     0.406250
gear   3.687500
carb   2.812500
newColumn1  0.46875
newColumn2  0.37500
newColumn3  0.15625
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: `mean` takes a vector as input. Your function takes a data.frame as input. `lapply` accepts only the former from the function passed as `FUN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `lapply`, you are applying a function to each column in isolation in your data frame. The problem here is that you want one of the columns split into three, which `lapply` doesn't do directly. However, it's easy to work around this:

```r
my.mean <- function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x) else prop.table(table(x))
setNames(as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.mean))), "mean")
#>               mean
#> mpg      20.090625
#> cyl       6.187500
#> disp    230.721875
#> hp      146.687500
#> drat      3.596563
#> wt        3.217250
#> qsec     17.848750
#> vs        0.437500
#> am        0.406250
#> gear      3.687500
#> carb      2.812500
#> gear1.3   0.468750
#> gear1.4   0.375000
#> gear1.5   0.156250
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can replace `unlist` +`lapply` with `sapply`.

Comment: @RonakShah I don't think you can on this occasion, because elements of different length are returned from the function. `sapply` won't automatically concatentate these into a vector in that case. For example, try `sapply(list(1, 2), function(x) if(x == 1) 1 else 1:2)`

Comment: I guess you are right. I didn't look this into much detail.