# Repeat the cell value in R based on if statement

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a code as below, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045066/customize-lapply-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127089/summary-statistic-with-ifelse-statement-in-r/67133363#67133363). I would like to repeat the factor cell values `gear1.3, gear1.4 gear1.5` as long as the column number. Many thanks in advance.

```
mtcars$gear1 <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels = c(3,4,5))
my.stats <- function(x){
  
  if(is.numeric(x)){ 
    
    funs <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR)
    lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = T))
   
    } else {prop.table(table(x))
  
    }}
  
lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.stats)
unlist(lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.stats))
as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.stats)))

setNames(as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(mtcars, FUN = my.stats))), c("mean", "median", "sd", "mad", "IQR"))
```

Expected Answer

```
              mean   median  sd  mad  IQR
X1            mean(X1)
X2            mean(X2)     
X3            
X4
X5
X6
gear1.3   prop.table(gear1.3)  prop.table(gear1.3) .....REPEAT
gear1.3   prop.table(gear1.4)  prop.table(gear1.4) .....REPEAT
gear1.5   prop.table(gear1.5)  prop.table(gear1.5) .....REPEAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the function to :

```
my.stats <- function(x){
  
  if(is.numeric(x)){ 
    
    data.frame(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
               sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), mad = mad(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
               IQR = IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    
  } else {
    do.call(rbind, lapply(prop.table(table(x)), function(p) {
        data.frame(mean = p, median = p, sd = p, mad = p, IQR = p)
    }))
  }
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(mtcars, my.stats))

#              mean    median          sd         mad       IQR
#mpg      20.090625  19.20000   6.0269481   5.4114900   7.37500
#cyl       6.187500   6.00000   1.7859216   2.9652000   4.00000
#disp    230.721875 196.30000 123.9386938 140.4763500 205.17500
#hp      146.687500 123.00000  68.5628685  77.0952000  83.50000
#drat      3.596563   3.69500   0.5346787   0.7042350   0.84000
#wt        3.217250   3.32500   0.9784574   0.7672455   1.02875
#qsec     17.848750  17.71000   1.7869432   1.4158830   2.00750
#vs        0.437500   0.00000   0.5040161   0.0000000   1.00000
#am        0.406250   0.00000   0.4989909   0.0000000   1.00000
#gear      3.687500   4.00000   0.7378041   1.4826000   1.00000
#carb      2.812500   2.00000   1.6152000   1.4826000   2.00000
#gear1.3   0.468750   0.46875   0.4687500   0.4687500   0.46875
#gear1.4   0.375000   0.37500   0.3750000   0.3750000   0.37500
#gear1.5   0.156250   0.15625   0.1562500   0.1562500   0.15625
```